# When editing a grid, how do I disable specific fields by row?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, grid

I have a kendo grid with data in it and multiple columns (say col 1, 2, and 3). Columns 1, 2, 3 need to be able to be edited (or preventing editing) based off the values of each other. This is row specific.

For instance, if column 1 (date) is < column 2 (date) then column 3 is not allowed to be edited.

I know it's simple enough to disable or enable an entire column but my requirements are row specific. So row 1 could have column 3 enabled and row 2 could have column 3 disabled.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Asking for clarification: are `readonly` formulas affecting the edition of the `cell` or the entire `row`? In your example, column 3 is not allowed to be edited (depending on column 1 and 2) but what happens with column 1 and 2, is it possible to edit them? The most general solution might require build a graph of dependencies between cells in a row and even detect cyclic dependencies (that should be considered as error).

Comment: alternative solution without custom editors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881484/make-cell-readonly-in-kendo-grid-if-condition-is-met/20881973#20881973

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My suggestion is creating an editor function that validates the condition. This of course has the disadvantage that is an ad-hoc solution but ... it works!

Lets have the following entries (data of the DataSource):

```
var entries = [
    { id:1, col1: new Date(2012, 11, 31), col2: new Date(2013, 0, 1), col3: "Yes" },
    { id:2, col1: new Date(2013, 0, 1), col2: new Date(2013, 0, 1), col3: "No" },
    { id:3, col1: new Date(2013, 0, 2), col2: new Date(2013, 0, 1), col3: "No" }
];
```

Then I define the grid as:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource : {
        data    : entries,
        schema  : {
            model: {
                id    : "id",
                fields: {
                    col1: { type: "date"},
                    col2: { type: "date"},
                    col3: { editable: true }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 3
    },
    columns    : [
        { field: "col1", title: "Col1", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" },
        { field: "col2", title: "Col2", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" },
        { field: "col3", title: "Edit?", editor: checkAndEdit }
    ],
    editable   : "incell",
    navigatable: true,
    pageable   : true
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Where `col1` and `col2` are dates and `col3` is a string that can be edited *if and only if* `col1` is less than `col2`.

I define `checkAndEdit` function as follow:

```
function checkAndEdit(container, options) {
    if (options.model.col1 < options.model.col2) {
        $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" ' +
                'data-format="' + options.format + '" ' +
                'class="k-input k-textbox"/>')
                .appendTo(container);
    } else {
        grid.closeCell(container);
    }
}
```

Where I generate the corresponding `input` field if `col1` < `col2` and otherwise invoke `closeCell` for exiting `edit` mode.

You can see it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/vrMzS/2/)

Comment: It seems this only works for "incell".  When doing "inline" the editor only gets triggered once and therefore you can't change one cell based on the contents of another.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple just use (Which you bind in your grid column)

`[Editable(false)]

     public string ob_name { get; set; }`

In your Costume class which using for your Kendo Ui Grid.

For details you can also [see this](http://atikpassion.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-disable-specific-grid-column-in.html)

Comment: By using data annotations, that worked for me, thanx @atik sarker  :)