# Kendo Grid cell enable/disable

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I am trying to enable or disable kendo grid Cell depend on other value in same row in MVC. 
I have tried

```
grid.dataSource.at(i).fields["colname"].editable = true;
```

but it affects all the rows column. I want only selected row's cell should disable/enable.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Look [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14221670/1267304) and tell if it helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make cell readonly in Kendo Grid if condition is met](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881484/make-cell-readonly-in-kendo-grid-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the edit event of the Grid and close the cell based on your condition. Same question is discussed [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/when-editing-a-grid-how-do-i-disable-specific-fields-by-row.aspx#nybmyAxjVE2FecbkBqVQzA).

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  //....
  edit: onEdit
});

function onEdit(e) {
  if(...your custom logic){
     $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pick up the selected row by .select() and then disable your cell.
for e.g

```
var grid = $("#grdName").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
```

this will give u the selected row and then you can disable/enable the cells